# Amazon VPC testing

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vpc, amazon-vpc

I sell a product that runs on Amazon EC2. A company now wants to purchase and install it within their perimeter... This also implies the use of a VPN connection to the EC2 datacenter.

I want to test my product using Amazon VPN (VPC) before handing over the code. Must I change my code to make it work across VPC? If I run on Windows, then wants the quickest and easiest desktop VPN client avaialable that will allow me to connect across VPN to the Amazon datacenter?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you setup NAT servers and set your routes in the AWS console. Your client can have some security infrastructure for extending their data center to the cloud - firewall rules at the VPC level etc. Disable firewall rules on the server you deploy to since your VPC already takes care of this. As root execute the following command. **service iptables stop** (you probably already know this I am guessing)

Is it important for your app to run across VPCs?
Depending on how large the company you are selling to is, their security team may give them the run around to have VPC to VPC communication. Is it important for your software to span across VPCs?